# Thymeleaf can't see For-each variable

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is my Service ( It just gets a list of entities )

```
  @Service
    public class ProcedureService {
        @Autowired
        ProcedureRepository procedureRepository;
    
    
        public List getProceduresList() {
            List<Procedure> procedureList;
            procedureList = procedureRepository.findAll();
            return procedureList;
        }
    
    }
```

Here is my Controller. It just puts list he gets to view.

```
    @Controller
public class ServicesController {
    @Autowired
    ProcedureService procedureService;


@GetMapping("/services")
public String getCustomer(Model model) {
    List<Procedure> procedures = procedureService.getProceduresList();
        model.addAttribute("procedures", procedures);
        return "services";
        }
}
```

And here is my real problem. Thyme leaf just doesn't see the entity in a List ( it sees the list though ). Here is my screen and full code of View

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>SpringMVC + Thymeleaf + Bootstrap 4 Table Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Customer Table</h1>
  <div class="row col-md-7 table-responsive">
    <table id="customerTable" class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr th:each="procedure: ${procedures}">
        <td th:text="${procedure.}" />
        <td th:text="${procedure.getId}" />
      </tr>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Can't resolve]

Comment: Hi Erwin. In your screenshot I think you have a rouge `</tr>` after the table row containing the error. Does removing that help?

Comment: @RichardWoods Thank you, I have edited it but it still can't see the entity

Comment: Well... that error highlighting is being added by you IDE (intellij?) rather than thymeleaf, do you get an error message when the code is run? If not it might be an issue with the Intellij themeleaf plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" in html so th wasn't really working.